# File uploading in react.js and Yii2 API

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, reactjs, yii2-advanced-app

I'm usin react.js(ver 15) and i want to upload the files with yii2 api.
My code is as follows:
My component(in react):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Heaader';    
/* global $ */    

class New extends Component {    

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    this.state = {
            cates: [],
            subcats: [],
            radioSelected: "f"
        };
    }    

    submitted = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        var file_data = $('#filee')[0].files;
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);    

        $.ajax({
        url: "http://blog.dev/ads",
        type: "POST",
        data:  form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){}
       });
    };    

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Header isNew="true" />
                <div style={{marginTop: 2 + 'em'}}>
                    <form onSubmit={this.submitted}>
                        <input type="file" id="filee" />
                        <button type="submit">Sub</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
}
```

Server Side:
In my controller:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;    

class AdsController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'frontend\models\Ads';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        // remove authentication filter
        $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
        unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

        // add CORS filter
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        ];

        // re-add authentication filter
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
        // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
        $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];

        return $behaviors;
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['create']);
        return $actions;
    }

    public function actionCreate()
    {
        print_r($_FILES);
    }
}
```

My problem is that $_FILES array is empty!
When I send data other than the file, $_POST works without problems(While this is the case in ajax request: processData:true and contentType:true ).
 but $_FILES is empty.
Please guide me and tell me where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your form has the correct encoding i.e `<form enctype=multipart/form-data>` for file uploads. this is most likely the reason why your `$_FILES` is empty
- Yii 2 specifies a uniform API for fetching/saving uploads by using `UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');` from the `yii\web\UploadedFile;` You should use it to access the uploads.

All the Best